# Find the length of $HI$ in the regular heptagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

I found the problem below in [Twitter](https://twitter.com/bilalsarimeseli/status/1287875912927600640)

$ABCDEFG$ is a regular heptagon. $EFHD$ is a rhombus and $HI$ is drawn perpendicular to side $AB$ find the length $HI(d)$

[image]

What I've done so far:

I can find the answer pretty easily by using trigonometric ratios. But I like to solve this using elementary geometry.

I found out that $E, H, I$ are collinear and $I$ is the midpoint of $AB$. Also, I drew lines $FD, EH, HA, HB$ but nothing helped me.

Could anyone help me to solve this?

Answers based on elementary geometry are much more appreciated.

Comment: Given internal angles of rhombus, a pure geometrical solution is unlikely. A little bit of trigonometry will be required.

Comment: Find $d(F,I)$ with $d(F,AB)$ and Pythagorean theorem, then use law of cosines in $\triangle FHI$ since it's easy to find $\angle FHI$.

Comment: @TheBestMagician Thank you very much for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a nice problem, which should have received more audience.
I'll try to give solutions that do not involve trigonometry. Arguably, the solution involving complex numbers is in essence also a trigonometric solution, this is but the bridge to a more geometric solution.

The side of the given regular heptagon is normed to one, as extracted from the picture.
Then it is enough to show $AH=BH=\sqrt 2$, thus getting rid of the more "complicated" point $I$, and have relations connecting only $H$ and the vertices. Equivalently, and giving up this norming, we have to show
$AH/AB=BH/AB=\sqrt 2$.

---

**First solution:** We are using complex numbers, fix $z$ to be the primitive root of unity given by $z=\exp\frac {2\pi i}7=\cos\frac {2\pi}7+i\sin\frac {2\pi}7$, and we will use below no functional equation of trigonometric / exponential nature, but only the algebraic relation
$$
\tag{$*$}
0 = 1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4 + z^5 + z^6\ .
$$
Consider the given regular heptagon with side one, and translate, rotate, and rescale it so that the vertices $A,B,C,\dots$ are mapped to their affixes, denoted by lower case corresponding letters, $a=1$, $b=z$, $c=z^2$, $\dots$ so that the parallelogram $DEFH$ is mapped to the parallelogram with vertices $d=z^3$, $e=z^4$, $f=z^5$, so that $h$, the image of $H$, is $
h = (d+f)-e=z^5-z^4+z^3$.
Then the lengths $AB$ and $BH$ are $|z-1|$, and $|z^5-z^4+z^3-z|=|z^4-z^3+z^2-1|$. The quotient $\displaystyle \frac{z^4-z^3+z^2-1}{z-1}$
is $z^3+z+1$.

So let us show:
$$
\sqrt 2\overset!=|z^3+z+1|\ , 
$$
which is a straightforward algebraic computation, using only $(*)$ and $z^7=1$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
|z^3+z+1|^2 
&=(z^3+z+1)\overline{(z^3+z+1)}\\
&=(z^3+z+1)(z^6+z^4+1)\\
&=(z^9+z^7+z^3)\ +\ (z^7+z^5+z)\ + \ (z^6+z^4+1)\\
&=1+1+(z^6+z^5+z^4+z^3+z^2+z+1)\\
&=2\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
$\square$

---

**Second solution:**

(Discussion and intermediate lemmas.)

Although short, the above computation does not have a *simple* geometrical interpretation,
which would be needed to rewrite geometrically the above "simple" algebraic solution
into a "simple" geometrical one. (This was more or less the question.)
We have to break into pieces, that may be easily translated. The core of the computation is
$$
BH^2
=
(h-b)\overline{(h-b)}
=
(z^5 - z^4 + z^3 - z)
\underbrace{\overline{(z^5 - z^4 + z^3 - z)}}_{=(z^2 -z^3 + z^4 - z^6)}
= 2\cdot 
(z-1)
\overline{(z-1)}
=2 AB^2\ .
$$
One step would be to construct *geometrically* the factor $(h-b)/(z-1)= z(z^3+z^2+1)$ that appears in
the computation.
Or $z^3+z^2+1$. Or $z^3+z+1$. Or $z(z^3+z+1)=z+z^2+z^4=z+z^4+z^9$.

This is done using a couple of lemmas.

---

**Lemma 1:** Let $ABCDEFG$ be a regular pentagon with side one and center $O$. Let $H=H_E$ be the point on $OE$ so that $DEFH_E$ is a rhombus. Similarly construct $H_A,H_B,\dots,H_G$. (Or rotate $H=H_E$.) Construct the $28$-gon $\Pi_{28}$ with one vertex in $E$ and center $D$, and (also) use labels for the vertices from $\Bbb Z/28$, such that $E=2$. Then $E=2$, $H_E=4$, $H_C=8$, and $C=12$ are among its vertices. Two other vertices are $S_E=EA\cap DF=4$, and $T_C=BD\cap CG=10$.

Then (recalling alternative notations $H=H_E=6$):
$$
BH_E=AH_E=AH_D=AT_C=DH_A=EH_A=EH_B=ES_C\ .
$$

[image: math stackexchange 4386141 lemma 1]

*Proof:*
We have $AH=EH$ because of the $OE$-reflection symmetry. Then $AH_E=AH_D$ by $OA$-symmetry. Then $T_C$ is constructed so that $DFGT_C$ is a parallelogram. So $DT_C=FG=1=DH_E$, so $\Delta DH_ET_C$ isosceles, and its angle bisector in $D$, the line $DH_CH_BA$, is thus the side bisector of the segment $H_ET_C$. The point $A$ lies on it, so $AH_E=AT_C$. We have so far
$$
BH_E=AH_E=AH_D=AT_C=\dots \text{ and }
$$
reflect w.r.t. the line $OC$, so the above chain of equalities can be continued:
$$
\dots = DH_B=EH_A=EH_B=ES_C\ .
$$
$\square$

---

*Comment:* It is then enough to show that any of the above segments has length $\sqrt 2$.
Arguably, this is in the same level of complexity as only the relation $AH_E=\sqrt 2$, but let us note the (psychological) difference.
In the given initial situation,
a helper construction to show a $\sqrt 2$ length segment could be done "in a natural manner" only (?) by constructing a square on a given side of length one.
After having Lemma 1, we have moved to a circle $(D)$ of radius one, and related to it $\sqrt 2$ is in a natural manner a chord length in the regular $28$-gon  $\Pi_{28}$, for instance the chord $29$ (or $E9$).

---

**Lemma 2:** In the situation of Lemma1, $H_A$ is the orthocenter in the triangle $\Delta$ with vertices $0$, $H_C=8$ and $C=12$.

*Proof:* Note that $08 \|26$, which is a direction perpendicular to the direction $FD \|GH_AC$, so $H_A$ is on the height from $C$ in $\Delta$.
Furthermore, $0$, $6=H_E$, and $H_A$ are collinear, since $06\|(-4,D,10)=DB\|H_EH_A$. From $C8O\perp H_EH_A$, the point $H_A$ is also on the height from $C$ in $\Delta$, so is its orthocenter.

$\square$

*Note:* Unfortunately, in the given picture i could not force a proof (by simple geometric arguments)
for $EH_A=E9$ (or $EH_C=E9$),
so the problem was moved to one in $\Delta$,
a triangle with sides chords in a regular $28$-gon inscribe in a circle with radius one.
So we move to a third Lemma, given in two equivalent settings, 3a and 3b.

---

**Lemma 3a:** Let $\Pi_{28}$ be a regular $28$-gon with vertices numbered $0,1,2,\dots$ with elements from the ring $\Bbb Z/28$ of integers taken modulo $28$. Let $D$ be its center, and assume that the circle $(D)=(0123\dots)$ has radius one. Let $\Delta$ be the triangle with vertices $0,8,12$. Then the distance from its circumcenter $D$ to its orthocenter $H_A$ is $\sqrt 2$.

In fact we need for $\Delta$ only three vertices from a regular heptagon.
So Lemma 3a is equivalent to the following:

**Lemma 3b:** Let $\Pi_7$ be the regular heptagon $ABCDEFG$ with center $O$, so that the radius of the circumscribed circle is $1=OA=OB=OC=OD=OE=OF=OG$. Let $H$ be the orthocenter of the triangle $\Delta$ with vertices $A,B,D$. Then the distance between the circumcenter $O$ and the orthocenter $H$ of $\Delta$ is $\sqrt 2$.

[image: math stackexchange 4386141 regular heptagon lemma 3]

*First proof (trigonometric):* In a general triangle with sides $a,b,c$ and circumradius $R$ the distance $d$ between its circumcenter and its orthocenter is given by the formula:
$$
d^2 =9R^2 - (a^2 + b^2 + c^2)\ .
$$
In our special case, the circumradius is $R=1$, and the sides $a,b,c$ are
$2\sin\frac\pi 7$,
$2\sin\frac{2\pi} 7$, and
$2\sin\frac{4\pi} 7$. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
a^2+b^2+c^2
&=
4\left(
\sin^2\frac{\pi}7 +
\sin^2\frac{2\pi}7 +
\sin^2\frac{4\pi}7 
\right)
\\
&=
2\left(
1-\cos\frac{2\pi}7 +
1-\cos\frac{4\pi}7 +
1-\cos\frac{8\pi}7 
\right)
\\
&=6 -
\left(
\cos\frac{2\pi}7 +
\cos\frac{4\pi}7 +
\cos\frac{6\pi}7 +
\cos\frac{8\pi}7 +
\cos\frac{10\pi}7 +
\cos\frac{12\pi}7 
\right)
\\
&= 6-(-1)=7\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then $d^2= 9-7=2$, showing the needed relation.

$\square$

*Second proof (algebraic):*
In essence, it is the same proof.
We can and do assume that $\Delta$ has circumcenter with aff ix zero in $\Bbb C$, and vertices with affix points $z$, $z^2=z^9$, and $z^4$. Its centroid is located at $(z + z^4 + z^9)/3$, so the orthocenter is on the line $OG$ at distance three times the length of $OG$ from $O$, so
$$
H= z + z^4 + z^9\ .
$$
This is a Gauss sum, a [Gauss period](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_period#Example),
which explains structurally the situation (from a number theoretic, rather than geometric point of view).
Since $p=7$ is three modulo four, $H$ is $(-1+\sqrt {-7})/2$, so $OH$ is the modulus $\sqrt 2$ of this number.

$\square$

*Third proof, a geometric proof:*
In essence, it is again the same proof.
Let us draw a new picture:

[image: math stackexchange 4386141 regular heptagon geometric solution]

Here $ABCDEFG$ is a regular heptagon, centered in $O$, and $\Gamma$ is so that $A\Gamma$ is a diameter.
Inscribed triangles in the circle $(O)$ with $A\Gamma$ as a side have a right angle opposite to it.
Let $B',C',D'$ be the projections of respectively $B,C,D$ on $A\Gamma$.

Again, we compute the distance $d$ between the center $O$ and the orthocenter $H$ of the triangle
$\Delta=\Delta ABD$ using the formula $d^2 = 9R^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)$, where $a,b,c$ are the lengths of the sides in $\Delta$ in this order, and then:
$$
\begin{aligned}
a^2 &= AB^2=A\Gamma\cdot AB'=2AB'\ ,\\
b^2 &= BD^2 =AC^2=A\Gamma\cdot AC'=2AC'\ ,\\
c^2 &= AD^2=A\Gamma\cdot AD'=2AD'\ ,\\
a^2+b^2+c^2
&=2AB'+2AC'+2AD'\\
&=\left|\ 2\overrightarrow{AB'}+2\overrightarrow{AC'}+2\overrightarrow{AD'}\ \right|\\
&=\left|\ \overrightarrow{AB}+ \overrightarrow{AG}
        +\overrightarrow{AC}+ \overrightarrow{AF}
        +\overrightarrow{AD}+ \overrightarrow{AE}\ \right|\\
&=\left|\ \overrightarrow{AB}+ \overrightarrow{AG}
        +\overrightarrow{AC}+ \overrightarrow{AF}
        +\overrightarrow{AD}+ \overrightarrow{AE}+ \overrightarrow{AA}\ \right|\\
&=\left|\ 7\overrightarrow{AO}\ \right|\\
&=7\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
using the fact that $O$ is the center of mass in $ABCDEFG$. This gives again
$$
d^2 = 9R^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2) = 9-7=2\ .
$$
$\square$

---

*Conclusion:* A geometric solution may work as follows:

Use *Lemma 1* to move *geometrically* the computation from a regular heptagon with side one
to a regular heptagon inscribed in a circle of radius one.
The length to be computed is now the distance from the circumcenter and the orthocenter
of a triangle with vertices among the vertices of the last regular heptagon.
Use *Lemma 2* and the geometric proof of *Lemma 3* to conclude the computation.
As ingredient we have used the [relation](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/arithmetic/algebra/DistanceOH.shtml) $OH^2 = 9R^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for spending your time for such a great solution